# How can I use UML to model a relationship between two classes, where one has functions exposed as friend to the other?

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

I have a two classes:

```
  ------------                         ---------------
     X                                       Y
  ------------                         ---------------
                      relation
  ------------    ------------------   ---------------
      A()                                   C()
      B()                             
      D()
      E()
  ------------                         ---------------
```

I want to inherit just these two functions from X class, where they are defined with the friend access modifier. My class will be:

```
 ---------------
      Y                                       
 ---------------

 ---------------
    C()
    A()
    D()
 ---------------
```

Y class uses some functions of X class namely A and D. How can I model this relationship in a UML class diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the methods of `X` are instance methods, you can use the [association relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_%28object-oriented_programming%29), which is a solid line between the two classes, however this might indicate to the reader of the model that the relationship is bidirectional. If an instance of `Y` maintains a reference to `X` in it and `X` does not maintain any kind of reference to 'Y', you can add the open-ended arrow to the end pointing toward X to add directionality. If `Y` can't exist without `X`, you can also consider using [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) to indicate this.

If the methods of `X` are static, consider the [dependency relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28UML%29), represented by a dotted line and open ended arrow from `Y` to `X`. This relationship is used `Y` calls static methods of `X` or if the functions of `Y` take `X` as a parameter but a reference to `X` is not maintained within an instance of `Y`.

In your specific case, when you're trying to model the `friend` relationship in C++, the information that I can find (such as [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002927/should-friend-functions-be-represented-in-uml-diagrams)) seems to suggest that you should annotate the members of `X` with the <> stereotype. From this point, I'd use either the association or dependency relationship discussed above, based on how `Y` is accessing `X`, with association if `Y` maintains an instance of `X` and dependency if `Y` receives instances of `X` as parameters to functions as they are needed.

Comment: Thanks so much, one last thing which free uml tool compatible with uml 2.0 should I use ? Staruml is not so compatible with uml 2.0. Thanks again

Comment: @user1796528 I can't answer that question. I'd recommend trying Eclipse's Papyrus plugin, though. It supports most of (maybe all) of UML 2.0 and most of SysML as well.